# Why go doesn't report "slice bounds out of range" in this case?

Tags: go, slice

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var v []int
    v = append(v,1)
    v = append(v,v[1:]...)
    fmt.Println("hi", v)

}
```

`v[1]` will report `index out of range`, but `v[1:]...` won't, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how spec defines slice expressions

> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= len(a), otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions

And that's how index expressions for slices are defined

> the index x is in range if 0 <= x < len(a), otherwise it is out of range
>
> if x is out of range at run time, a run-time panic occurs

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions

For your example:

`v[1]` panics because it's our of range as per the definition above (because `1` does not qualify the `0 <= x < len(a)` reqirement)

`v[1:]` runs fine because it's identical to `v[1:len(v)]` and fits the `if 0 <= low <= high <= cap(a)` requirement.

Comment: This doesn't explain why behaviour is different for  `v[1]` and `v[1:]...` for the same slice

Comment: @user3698446 runtime behaviour regarding index boundary check is the same for both `v[1:]` and `v[1:]...`

Comment: I mean `v[1]` and `v[1:]...`, it was a typo,sorry

Comment: Yep, I added the quote for indexing as well

Comment: I think this still doesn't explain the difference..

Comment: @user3698446 what's not clear? The quotes explain in what case the panic will occur. They both explain why `v[1]` would panic and `v[1:]` would not.

Comment: The difference lies in whether it's `index` or `range` op, it has nothing to do whether it's `array` or `slice`.

Comment: @user3698446 it's actually both. Range operation for slices and arrays and strings behaves slightly differently. But all the important semantics are quoted in this answer. Click those links and carefully read the corresponding sections.

Comment: Can you update the answer to make it more explicit instead of implicit?

Comment: I just did a second ago

Comment: I think your answer still doesn't explain well why `v[1]` fits in `0 <= low <= high < len(a)` but `v[1]...` fits in `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, but I will accept it because it's the most close to the perfect answer...

Comment: @user3698446 `v[1]` does not fit `0 <= low <= high < len(a)`, that check is only for range expressions. Checks for single index and slice expressions are **DIFFERENT** and explained in different spec sections (which I both referred and quoted)

Comment: So the real reason lies in whether it's `range` or `index`, still has little to do whether it's array or slice anyway.

Comment: @user3698446 it makes difference for arrays and slices, it's whether `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)` or `0 <= low <= high <= cap(a)`. Mentioning that difference is still required to be able to explain the runtime behaviour. Eg: `v[2:2]` would still be valid for your very code.

Comment: I see, but your answer doesn't make all this explicit, I think that's why it's not voted by others even I have accepted it..

Comment: @user3698446 my answer quotes the spec that says exactly that: "For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.". I personally tend to think that people just don't like reading 2 paragraphs of the spec, and prefer looking at examples that provide imprecise approximations.

Comment: I see, that's why I accepted it.But it's still not explicit enough, readers has to follow the links to finally understand that you are right

Comment: @user3698446 that's the idea: you cannot quote the complete spec here, if one needs a deeper understanding - they must read the source of truth. Any approximation would be in the best case incomplete, in the worst case - plain wrong. It's up to what your aim is. If you read my answer you could have explained why `v[2:2]` is valid, if you read both other answers - you wouldn't.

Comment: they don't need to if you can make your answer more explicitly, anyway, your answer is fine to me, I'll accept it:)

Comment: "v[1] panics because it's our of range as per the definition above (because 1 does not qualify the 0 <= x < len(a) reqirement)" 

How is this correct? An index of 1 *does* meet the 0 <= x < len(a) reqirement because len(a) is 1.

Comment: In the text I just quoted, you aren't using an interval, you are using a single index.

Comment: @LukeGehorsam it is an interval described by condition `0 <= x < len(a)`. You have quoted it. And `x=1` **DOES NOT** meet the requirement, because `1 < 1` is false. Are you sure you understand the `0 <= x < len(a)` notation? Any chance you re-read the answer **CAREFULLY** before you leave another comment? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

v[1:] returns a list type. Here an empty list is returned as nothing comes in the slice range specified. Hence no error is thrown.

v[1] is trying to access element explicitly out of bound. No default value is returned hence an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to reference an empty slice just past the last element, because this can be useful when implementing things.

Eg.

```
 s := make([]byte, n)
 // Fill s with something...
 for len(s) > 0 { 
      b := s[0] // Get next byte
      s = s[1:] // Remove it from the slice
      // Deal with byte
 }
```

...the last removal wouldn't be valid if s[1:1] didn't work on a 1 byte slice.